# Write records into text file from database using java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-server, resultset

I want to store database records to text file. for that I used the ResultSet, I have selected the whole table using sql select query and store the data in the ArrayList. But this code doesn't work properly. my database name is test and table is employee. what should I do? this is what I have tried.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ResultSetWriteInToTextFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            List data = new ArrayList();
            try {
                    Connection con = null;
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                    Statement st = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from employee");

                    while (rs.next()) {
                            String id = rs.getString("emp_id");
                            String name = rs.getString("emp_name");
                            String address = rs.getString("emp_address");
                            String contactNo = rs.getString("contactNo");
                            data.add(id + " " + name + " " + address + " " + contactNo);

                    }
                    writeToFile(data, "Employee.txt");
                    rs.close();
                    st.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
            }
    }

    private static void writeToFile(java.util.List list, String path) {
            BufferedWriter out = null;
            try {
                    File file = new File(path);
                    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
                    for (String s : list) {
                            out.write(s);
                            out.newLine();

                    }
                    out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: Why are you using a [raw type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)? Also, what part doesn't work properly? Is there an Exception? Do you get the wrong output?

Comment: What does it mean "But this code doesn't work properly"?

Comment: when I'm compiling exception will occur

Comment: @JProgrammer Is it on `(String s : list)`? Because that's a raw type.

Comment: @elliott oh!!! what should I do. can u correct it? pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
for (String s : list) {
```

to

```
for (Object s : list) {
```

Comment: I have don. but now error at
 out.write(s);

Comment: Great. Change out.write(s) to out.write((String) s)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use for `(String s : data) {}`. You have no where mentioned that data is a List of Strings. Declare it as `List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();`. Hope you are using Java 1.5 or higher.

Also you need to give an absolute file path.

```
String path = "D:/Sample/Employee.txt" //whatever path you are using
File file = new File(path);
File parent_directory = file.getParentFile();
if (parent_directory != null) {
   parent_directory.mkdirs();
}
```

Comment: are u sure???? I have tried this way. not running

Comment: Have you included the code for creating parent folders? Also make sure that you have write access to the path that you provide.

Comment: @JProgrammer, Have updated the answer, pointing out one more issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use raw types! Change `List data = new ArrayList();` to

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and change `writeToFile(java.util.List list, String path) {` to

```
writeToFile(java.util.List<String> list, String path) {
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your file path is correct, and that all of the directories exist.

Also, you have a try-catch statement in `writeToFile`. That method is called inside another try-catch statement. In the function declaration for `writeToFile`, try something like this:

```
private static void writeToFile(java.util.List list, String path) throws IOException`
```

You can then remove the try-catch statement in `writeToFile`, as if that exception is thrown, it is handled by the try-catch in the main method.

If that doesn't work, make sure that your code is connecting to the database properly.